# What does "=>" mean in PHP?

Tags: php

What does the `=>` operator mean in the following code?

```
foreach ($user_list as $user => $pass)
```

The code is a comment at PHP.net.
The user does not specify the value of `$user_list`, `$user` or `$pass`.
I normally see that `=>` means equal or greater than.

However, I am not sure about its purpose here because it is not assigned.
I read the code as

1. process a list of users in integers
2. such that the value of each user is equal or greater than password

The above does not make sense to me.

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot the 'array' keyword.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758791/what-does-k-v-in-foreachex-as-k-v-mean

Comment: @Masi Mistake on my side. Sorry.

Comment: I would say => assigns a value to the array and uses a key as an index. So in your case, the array which you call $user_list uses $user as an index key. The foreach loop loops and assigns to every element in that array the value $pass.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

`=>` is the separator for associative arrays. In the context of that foreach loop, it assigns the key of the array to `$user` and the value to `$pass`.

Example:

```
$user_list = array(
    'dave' => 'apassword',
    'steve' => 'secr3t'
);

foreach ($user_list as $user => $pass) {
    echo "{$user}'s pass is: {$pass}\n";
}
// Prints: 
// "dave's pass is: apassword"
// "steve's pass is: secr3t"
```

Note that this can be used for numerically indexed arrays too.

Example:

```
$foo = array('car', 'truck', 'van', 'bike', 'rickshaw');
foreach ($foo as $i => $type) {
    echo "{$i}: {$type}\n";
}
// prints:
// 0: car
// 1: truck
// 2: van
// 3: bike
// 4: rickshaw
```

Answer (score 27):

It means assign the key to $user and the variable to $pass

When you assign an array, you do it like this

```
$array = array("key" => "value");
```

It uses the same symbol for processing arrays in foreach statements. The '=>' links the key and the value.

According to the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), the '=>' created key/value pairs.

Also, Equal or Greater than is the opposite way: '>='. In PHP the greater or less than sign always goes first: '>=', '<='.

And just as a side note, excluding the second value does not work like you think it would. Instead of only giving you the key, It actually only gives you a value:

```
$array = array("test" => "foo");

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . " : " . $value; // Echoes "test : foo"
}

foreach($array as $value)
{
    echo $value; // Echoes "foo"
}
```

Comment: Your last example has something wrong, since I get the error message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /var/www/cha.php on line 2`.

Comment: Ooops Forgot to add the Array Keyword. Try that

Answer (score 13):

Code like "a => b" means, for an associative array *(some languages, like [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), if I remember correctly, call those "hash")*, that 'a' is a key, and 'b' a value.

You might want to take a look at the documentations of, at least:

- [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Here, you are having an array, called `$user_list`, and you will iterate over it, getting, for each line, the key of the line in `$user`, and the corresponding value in `$pass`.

For instance, this code:

```
$user_list = array(
    'user1' => 'password1',
    'user2' => 'password2',
);

foreach ($user_list as $user => $pass)
{
    var_dump("user = $user and password = $pass");
}
```

Will get you this output:

```
string 'user = user1 and password = password1' (length=37)
string 'user = user2 and password = password2' (length=37)
```

*(I'm using [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/var_dump) to generate a nice output, that facilitates debuging; to get a normal output, you'd use [`echo`](http://www.php.net/echo))*

"Equal or greater" is the other way arround: "greater or equals", which is written, in PHP, like this; ">="

The Same thing for most languages derived from C: C++, JAVA, PHP, ...

As a piece of advice: If you are just starting with PHP, you should definitely spend some time *(maybe a couple of hours, maybe even half a day or even a whole day)* going through some parts of the manual :-)

It'd help you much!

Answer (score 8):

An array in PHP is a map of keys to values:

```
$array = array();
$array["yellow"] = 3;
$array["green"] = 4;
```

If you want to do something with each key-value-pair in your array, you can use the `foreach` control structure:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

The $array variable is the array you will be using. The $key and $value variables will contain a key-value-pair in every iteration of the `foreach` loop. In this example, they will first contain "yellow" and 3, then "green" and 4.

You can use an alternative notation if you don't care about the keys:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
```

Comment: Is "foreach" really an operator? Do you have a source?

Comment: Technically speaking, it's a control structure: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php 
I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in PHP are associative arrays (otherwise known as dictionaries or hashes) by default. If you don't explicitly assign a key to a value, the interpreter will silently do that for you. So, the expression you've got up there iterates through `$user_list`, making the key available as `$user` and the value available as `$pass` as local variables in the body of the `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

`$user_list` is an array of data which when looped through can be split into it's name and value.

In this case it's name is `$user` and it's value is `$pass`.