# What does $k => $v in foreach($ex as $k=>$v) mean?

Tags: php, foreach

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does “=>” mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819)

What does `$k => $v` mean?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: "im not a php expert" That's why the manual exists...

Comment: something prevents you from running the code?

Comment: *(related)* [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Exact duplicate: [What does “=>” mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means that for every key-value pair in the traversable variable `$ex`, the key gets assigned to `$k` and value to `$v`. In other words:

```
$ex = array("1" => "one","2" => "two", "3" => "three");
foreach($ex as $k=>$v) {
   echo "$k : $v \n";
}
```

outputs:

```
1 : one
2 : two
3 : three
```

Answer (score 5):

`$k` is the index number where the `$v` value is stored in an array. `$k` can be the associative index of an array:

```
$array['name'] = 'shakti';
$array['age'] = '24';

foreach ($array as $k=>$v)
{
    $k points to the 'name' on first iteration and in the second iteration it points to age.
    $v points to 'shakti' on first iteration and in the second iteration it will be 24.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looping over an array. Arrays have keys (numbers, or could be strings when you have an associative array) and values that 'belong' to those keys.

Your `$k` is the key, the `$v` is the value, and you're looping trough each separate pair with a foreach.