# PHP equals arrow operator in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $k => $v in foreach($ex as $k=>$v) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758791/what-does-k-v-in-foreachex-as-k-v-mean)

I am trying to understand what this means:

```
foreach($this->domains as $domain=>$users) {  

// some code...

}
```

I understand `$this->domains` is an array that `foreach` will index over. But what does `as $domain=>$users` mean? I have only seen the `=>` operator used in an array to set (key, value) pairs. The class has a member called `$domain`, but I assume that would be accessed as `$this->domain`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `=>` operator specifies an association. So assuming `$this->domains` is an array, `$domain` will be the key, and `$users` will be the value.

```
<?php
$domains['example.com'] = 'user1';
$domains['fred.com'] = 'user2';

foreach ($domains as $domain => $user) {
    echo '$domain, $user\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
example.com, user1
fred.com, user2
```

(In your example, `$users` is probably an array of users);

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way:

```
foreach($this->domains as $key=>$value) {
```

It will step through each element in the associative array returned by `$this->domains` as a key/value pair.  The **key** will be in `$domain` and the **value** in `$users`.

To help you understand, you might put this line in your `foreach` loop:

```
echo $domain, " => ", $users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each
>   loop, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the
>   internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next loop, you'll
>   be looking at the next element).
>
> The second form does the same thing, except that the current element's
>   key will be assigned to the variable $key on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

`$domain` here is a local variable that contains the key of the current item in the array. That is if your array is:

```
$ages = array("dad" => 31, "mom" => 35, "son" => 2);
```

Then

```
foreach($ages as $name=>$age) 
{  
   // prints dad is 32 years old, mom is 35 years old, etc
   echo "$name is $age years old"

}
```

In the loop body, referring to `$name` would refer to the current key, ie "dad", "mom" or "son". And `$age` would refer to the age we've stored above at the current key.

> assume that would be accessed as $this->domain.

You're right, just `$domain` is the local variable here. You need `$this->domain` to get the member variable.