# Question on arguments inside PHP foreach statement

Tags: php

I have below code. But I cannot understand what is meant by `$seat_key => $seat` in `foreach`. In other terms, I understand `foreach ($seats as $seat)`, but not `foreach ($seats as $seat_key => $seat)`

```
foreach ($seats as $seat_key => $seat) {

    $email_found = false;

    foreach ($email_accounts as $key => $email_account) {

        if (strtolower($email_account->email) == strtolower($seat->email) && empty($email_account->deactivated_since) && empty($email_account->flg_deleted)) {
            unset($seats[$seat_key]);
            unset($email_accounts[$key]);
            $email_found = true;

            if (isset($email_found_seats[$seat->email])) {
                $email_duplicated_seats[] = $seat;
            } else {
                $email_found_seats[$seat->email] = $seat;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP equals arrow operator in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732013/php-equals-arrow-operator-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` construct when used in this way will allow you to obtain both the *key* and the *value* of the item when enumerating the array or object.

In the case of the example, the statement is:

```
foreach ($seats as $seat_key => $seat)
```

This means that for each enumerated item, the *key* of the item will be stored in `$seat_key` and the *value* of the item will be stored in `$seat`.

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) has a great, detailed explanation of this but for reference the function declaration in the manual is shown as:

```
foreach (iterable_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```