# What does => mean in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “=>” mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)

I'm learning about arrays and am not certain what => means or does.

Comment: Have you seen the manual about arrays? Also see [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: This question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Assignment of a value to a named key.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

```
$example = array('color' => 'blue');
echo $example['color']; //prints blue
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just syntax for writing array literals that behave like maps / dictionaries.

$mydict = array('hello' => 'world');

The above is an array with one element. But instead if indexing that element with an integer index, you use the key `'hello'`:

echo $mydict['hello']