# PHP syntax, what does '=>' mean other than array assignment?

Tags: php, cakephp, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does “=>” mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Check this:
`var $hasAndBelongsToMany => array('Member' => 'User');`
What does the sign `=>` mean? the second one I know, but what is the first `=>`?

I saw it in the cakePhp manual.

Link add: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#

Comment: Where's the link to the CakePHP documentation page where you saw it? So that we could see the context.

Comment: have you tried to use the SQ-search before askig this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php - doesn't this solve you problem?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. He is is acking whether => has any other meaning than array item assignment.

Comment: This is *not* an exact duplicate of that question. This operator is in the CakePHP documentation here http://book.cakephp.org/view/1040/Relationship-Types and I have no idea what it means, I suspect it has a CakePHP-specific meaning.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, pity that it was closed before you actually understood the question..

Comment: I renamed the title in the hopes that others will catch on and reopen ;)

Comment: To answer your question: No there is no other meaning for `=>`. It's invalid syntax, used in the documentation for illustrative purposes. (Or just a typo like the answers say.)

Comment: just copy the class into a file and run `php -l filename.php` on that file to lint it and you'll see it gives a `syntax error, unexpected '=>', expecting ',' or ';'`. Any decent IDE will also mark this as a syntax error. There is no need to reopen that question. Typos in the CakePHP manual are too localized. The only other use of `=>` is in `foreach` loops and that's already linked in the reference topic.

Comment: It's a typo. Compare it to the other associations.

Comment: Got it all. thanks. and tho i agree that it shouldn't be reopened , i think that it was closed long before they read it at all. not a way to do things.
and again, thanks all!

Comment: @yossi - in some ways it *is* a duplicate, in that people have linked you to *what `=>` means*; the fact that it doesn't mean anything in your context (it is invalid) fully supports this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an mistake.
$var assignments are with a singe '=', that '>' shouldn't be there. It produces an parse error.

Comment: Yepp seems like a mistake - the official manual got it right http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

Comment: Official manual contains the text provided by OP. "var $hasAndBelongsToMany => array('Member' => 'User');" found in Cake PHP manual here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1040/Relationship-Types

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it looks like a typo. I found the CakePHP manual and only find instances of `$hasAndBelongsToMany = array(...`, not `=> array`.

Comment: Look harder: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1040/Relationship-Types

Comment: So it's a mistake the rest of the book doesn't make.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP documentation doesn't know such operator in any other than array item assignment context.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

So, it is a typo.