# What is this operator "=>"?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “=>” mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I see this symbol in a lot of PHP code.

I can't figure out what it means or what it does..

Is it really an operator ?

Comment: Can you give an example of its use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) and more specifically for example [What does “=>” mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean `=>`? If so, it's for initializing array keys (or indexes if you prefer). Like this:

```
$values = array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
);
```

This will initiazlie an array with a key named foo with a value of bar.

Read more on about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) at php.net.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php