# What is this: wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and php.  I saw the line of code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

I understand that it is a generating my nav menu, but I would really like to get in there and change things.

Where is the array defined, and what is this => operator?  What is this array access doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just passes a `"primary"` into the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function. And the `=>` is quite simply the syntax for declaring arrays. It's a array declaration, not an access.

See also the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
or [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
and [What does "=>" mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)