# What is the difference between => and -> in php?

Tags: php, operators

What is the difference between `=>` and `->` in php? and when i should use those ? i know that -> can be use in object  like `$obj->foo` and `=>` is in array is there any other place we can use them ?

Comment: [reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link will provide you a full list of symbols and their usage.

## [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Since you have asked, In short

`=>` is called [T_DOUBLE_ARROW](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) and is the separator for associative arrays, the '=>' created key/value pairs.

`->` is called "object operator" or [T_OBJECT_OPERATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) and it's used when you want to call a method on an instance or access an instance property.

Answer (score 1):

As chandresh said but with examples:

=> is for **associative** arrays.  You would do such:

```
$arr = array("key" => "value"); // now value can be access simply by typing $arr['key'];
```

-> is for accessing object properties(variables) and methods(functions)

```
// instead of doing this:
calculate();

// if you have created an object, you could access the method(function) like so:

$object->calculate();  // to call method(function) inside a class\object
```

Comment: thank-you ... for you help i really do appreciate

Answer (score 0):

One is a scope resolution operator and the other is an array control method to define Keys/values

[What's the difference between :: (double colon) and -> (arrow) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/whats-the-difference-between-double-colon-and-arrow-in-php)      For the `->` syntax and:

[What does "=>" mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)   for the `=>` syntax