# What does this => Operator mean?

Tags: php

I tried searching on Google, but can't seem to find out what does this operator really mean in PHP?

```
=>
```

Any help please?

Comment: What's the context? That would probably help.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Look on the right side of this page.

Answer (score 3):

`=>` is the separator for associative arrays. In the context of that foreach loop, it assigns the key of the array to the value.

[What does "=>" mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)