# Can someone explain me a php code

Tags: php

So i was searching it online but i couldn't find a basic explanation. I am new with php. So i am going to say what i understand out of this code.

foreach is that it's using multiple $name and the AS makes the first variable the same as the second $key but then comes => which i don't understand.

if $min higher than $val , $min = $val and the one under is the opposite.

What is => exactly doing?

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
if($min > $val){
$min = $val;
}
 if($max < $val){
$max = $val;
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing really.. But it's needed to have a foreach with both key and value. The ( doesn't do anything either but you need it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php read this, this question is about that double arrow operator in php.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about how and why a syntax is the way it is and is not suited on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "=>" mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: it is a seperator in associative arrays .here it means foreach `$val` ( value ) of `$key`. it is like saying look into the value of the key in the `foreach` loop. allows exposing the `$val`

Comment: Correction, the second statement doesn't do the opposite. Be aware the opposite would be <= (less or equal).

Comment: I am also trying to resolve this problem. `if ($tickets % 10 == 0) {
 
 
 $sum = $tickets *2 - 2;
 

 
}`........... Now if i insert 10/20/30/40 inside the input field it will calculate the total - 2euro. But at 20 its needs to calculate 20 - 4 and at 30 - 6 at 40 - 8. How do i do that?

Comment: I am asking here because i can't ask questions for 2 day's. I don't understand that, i alway's ask questions after searching the internet for a hour. And i am in the beginning of learning php which i am ambitiouse about so why block my question limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an array:

```
$array = [
   'monkey' => 1,
   'dog'    => 2,
   'bird' => 3
   ];
```

The `foreach` loops trough all the elements of the array:

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value){ ... }
             ^        ^        ^
             |        |        |
         the array   the key:  the value:
                     monkey       1
                     dog          2
                     bird         3
```

Inside the foreach you can then manipulate the array. For example:

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value){
    if( $value > 1 )                        //true for dog and bird
        {
        $array [ $key ] = $value + 10;      //dog now is 12, bird becomes 13
        }
    }
```

If you only need the values, you can leave the `key =>` part out:

```
foreach ( $array as $value){
      if( $value > 1 )
         { 
         echo $value;                       // echo's 2 and 3
         }
      }
```

Comment: I am also trying to resolve this problem. `if ($tickets % 10 == 0) { $sum = $tickets *2 - 2; }`........... Now if i insert 10/20/30/40 inside the input field it will calculate the total - 2euro. But at 20 its needs to calculate 20 - 4 and at 30 - 6 at 40 - 8. How do i do that?

Comment: I am asking here because i can't ask questions for 2 day's. I don't understand that, i alway's ask questions after searching the internet for a hour. And i am in the beginning of learning php which i am ambitiouse about so why block my question limit.